# Problem installing package e1071 on jupyter notebook for Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, e1071

I am having some problems making the package e1071 work on my jupyter notebook R. I tried installing it however, I would still get the same error after running the confusion matrix. I used install.packages(“e1071”) and also tried on the command terminal but did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks. Here is the code: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq3Ta.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `install.packages("e1071")` in the R console and then `library("e1071")`. That should work.